# A tiny edit to Mysql query to edit some links in my database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I want to remove all the http://www.domain.com/?h from my mySQL database. ( the 'h' is because I have some posts that starts with ?p and I dont want to edit them ) and replace them with my new domain. The structure of my database is like below and the SQL query I have returns me an error. How can I fix that?

TABLE: wp_posmeta

meta_key : _tdomf_custom_permalink

meta_value : http://www.domain.com/?http://theirdomain.blogspot.com/..../.../...html

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta set _tdomf_custom_permalink = replace(_tdomf_custom_permalink, 'http://www.domain.com/?h', 'http://www.newdomain.com') WHERE _tdomf_custom_permalink like 'http://www.domain.com/?h%'
```

And the error I get is : **Unknown column '_tdomf_custom_permalink' in 'where clause'**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace all `_tdomf_custom_permalink` with `meta_value`? :)

Comment: Nope. `damn message length restriction force me to write this useless sentence`

Answer (score 0):

There's no column in that table called "_tdomf_custom_permalink", that should be a value on a row in the column "meta_value"

so that becomes

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'http://theDomainYouHaveNow.com', 'http://theDomainYourWantAfterUpdate.com') WHERE meta_key = '_tdomf_custom_permalink'